# How to I make an activity close when minimised

Tags: android, eclipse

I've made an app and I want the apps mainactivity to stop when the app's minimised. So when the app gets maximised again then it will be just like it opened fresh.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably look at this function: [onUserLeaveHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29)

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to go into the background as the result of user choice. For example, when the user presses the Home key...

You can call finish() in this function

Example how to override the function in your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();

    finish();
}
```

Comment: I am pretty new to coding, I'm not sure how to use this.. The google developers page didn't help me much, do you know where I could learn it?

Comment: Override the onUserLeaveHint() function in your Activity like you would do the onPause() function. I've updated my answer with an example.